Can I still cook and eat farro that fermented?
I soaked my farro too long and it started to ferment. Can I still cook and eat it?

Can you provide more information?  How long was it soaking and a what temperature?  Any other observations, such as unpleasant or sour smells (beyond mild/pleasant fermentation), mold, discoloration, and/or sliminess?
